hosting a flask app in AWS lambda with API requests from teams bot
I am trying to host a teams bot on AWS, the message endpoint is set to the api gateway from the lambda function. The goal is for it to just send "message" back, however upon testing it gives me this:
{
"errorMessage": "'httpMethod'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"requestId": "b1d5275e-60cc-489f-8079-0fc701412b69",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/app.py", line 72, in lambda_handler\n    return awsgi.response(app, event, context)\n",
"  File "/opt/python/awsgi/init.py", line 172, in response\n    output = app(environ(event, context), sr)\n",
"  File "/opt/python/awsgi/init.py", line 121, in environ\n    'REQUEST_METHOD': event['httpMethod'],\n"
]
}
here is app.py:
import sys
import traceback
import json
from datetime import datetime
import awsgi
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from botbuilder.core import BotFrameworkAdapterSettings, TurnContext, BotFrameworkAdapter
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes
from bot import MyBot
from config import DefaultConfig

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

# Create adapter.
SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(CONFIG.APP_ID, CONFIG.APP_PASSWORD)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)

# Catch-all for errors.
async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):
    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    # Send a message to the user
    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")
    await context.send_activity("To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.")

    # Send a trace activity if we're talking to the Bot Framework Emulator
    if context.activity.channel_id == "emulator":
        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="TurnError",
            name="on_turn_error Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value=f"{error}",
            value_type="https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
        )
        await context.send_activity(trace_activity)

ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error

# Create the Bot
BOT = MyBot()

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/messages", methods=["POST"])
def messages():
    if request.headers.get("Content-Type") == "application/json":
        body = request.json
    else:
        return "Unsupported Media Type", 415

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)
    auth_header = request.headers.get("Authorization", "")

    # Create a task to handle the incoming activity
    async def aux_func(turn_context):
        await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(aux_func(TurnContext(activity)))

    return jsonify({"status": "Message processed"}), 201

# AWS Lambda handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return awsgi.response(app, event, context)

here is bot.py:
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext
#from agent_service import invoke_agent


class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    # See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        #response = invoke_agent(turn_context.activity.text)
        await turn_context.send_activity(f'message!')


I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what

awsgi is no longer maintained and has several known issues.  I'd suggest you find an alternative.

what would an alternative be?

update: changed it to this, problem still not solved
return aws_lambda_wsgi.response(app, event, context)
